# mysterious emails from phpmailer

Tags: php, html, web

I have the following file

email.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("emailUtil.php");


//Get form variables
    $name       = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
    $email      = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
    $subject    = $_REQUEST['subject'] ;
    $message    = $_REQUEST['message'] ;

$result = sendEmail($name, $email, $subject, $message);
.
.
.
?>
```

the function sendEmail is defined in emailUtil.php and it basically uses phpmailer library to send me an email with the following format:

```
Name: $name          <br>
Email: $email        <br>
Subject: $subject    <br>
Message:             <br>
<p>
$msg
</p>
<br>
<br>
IP Address: $ip
```

Every day at 9:38 pm from IP address 69.175.118.170 I am receving an email with the above format and is exactly this:

```
        Name: 1
        Email: 1
        Subject: 1
        Message : 1
        IP Address: 69.175.118.170
```

I did a search in my entire website, the only time I post anything to email.php is from a contact form like so:

```
<form id="contacts-form" method="post" action="php/email.php" target="myiframe">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="contactname" value="" required>
.
.
<iframe  name="myiframe" id="myiframe" src="" style="visibility:hidden"></iframe>
</form>
```

I can't figure out what/who is sending me these emails?!

I don't know what else to say, and I don't know what to do next, I hoped someone here would have an idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ISP is `SingleHop`
This is NOT google, but some other `bot` roaming your page.
You should add additional security params.

Comment: BUT! you can't send an email value of "1" from my contact from, jquery doesn't allow it

Comment: @Kam jQuery wouldn't have anything to do with a curl request.

Comment: I have several procedures in place, and I get spammed about once a week. It's the nature of `PHP` and people knowing *every loophole that exists* that write bots to query any files on your domain.

Comment: sorry maybe I am not explaining myself correctly, or I just don't get it, please visit http://formationmtl.com/contact.php and fill it with 1 everywhere and click send :)   it won't work :$
So if you can't do it, how does this bot?

Comment: Done (minus email address). Wanna see MY authentication I get spammed with? Let me know how a bot would trick THIS, cause I can't figure it out... [Here is a live version of my contact form](http://sinsysonline.com/repair/contact.html)

Comment: Ahhhh, do you mind, if I edit the question and ask for solutions so you can maybe expand your answer on possible solutions?

Comment: Unfortunately (look at my answer) I'm still trying to figure out how the bot is roaming through click events...

Comment: Do you think I can block his IP address since it seams constant? or is that not practical?

Comment: Totally could, but my expertise is in JS. Wouldn't know server side code to do so.

Comment: FYI, I will basically just extract his IP address from $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] and when it matches the above IP address, would not allow him to send an email :)

Answer (score 2):

Google. The google bot crawls your web site, and while doing so hits the button to see if anything shows up.
edit: yes, sorry, this is not google, but singlehop.

Comment: BUT! you can't send an email value of "1" from my contact from, jquery doesn't allow it

Comment: jquery is client side, meaning it can be ignored. Now, google is pretty smart so it checks your javascript codes so it wont crawl a div  that never shows up, for example. As for that the "1" part, google is not browsing your site and filling out textboxes. It sees your button leads to a link that requires certain parameters, and says "ok" to whatever your server requests.

Comment: sorry gonna comment here instead of up above, it requires 50 rep and I dont have it. "how can you query that?" like so, http://formationmtl.com/contact.php?name=1&email=1&subject=1&message=1

Comment: Ah ok, I understand. here's a +1 :)

Comment: Also again, I cant comment because of rep but can you please comment to the user below that the bot does not perform click effects, it just renders html, -as in reads html code, like text- and hits every link it can. And does this for everything and everyway. For solution, you can add a captcha or block that ip. singlehop isnt important for anyone.